# NSArray reverse index sort

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, sorting

Here is my `NSArray`

```
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", nil];
```

Now I'm looping through the array like this:

```
int size = [myArray count];
NSLog(@"there are %d objects in the myArray", size);

for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    NSString * buttonTitle = [myArray objectAtIndex:i]; 
    // This gives me the order a, b, c, d, e 
    // but I'm looking to sort the array to get this order
    // e,d,c,b,a

    // Other operation use the i int value so i-- doesn't fit my needs
}
```

In the for loop this gives me the order:

```
a, b, c, d, e
```

but I'm looking to sort the array to get this order:

```
e, d, c, b, a
```

Any thoughts?

I need to keep the array in the original sort order as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try calling [`reverseObjectEnumerator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/reverseObjectEnumerator) on the array and using a for-in loop to cycle through the objects:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];

// Interate through array backwards:
for (NSString *buttonTitle in [myArray reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", buttonTitle);
}
```

This will output:

```
c
b
a
```

Alternatively, you can reverse the array in place if you'd like to iterate through the array by index or do something else with it:

```
NSArray *reversedArray = [[myArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, still have to test but this looks like it. Big thanks!

Comment: You can use a `for` loop directly on the `reverseObjectEnumerator`.  There is probably no reason to use `allObjects` to create a new array.  Just do `for (NSString *buttonTitle in myArray.reverseObjectEnumerator) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

That or change your loop

```
for(int i = size; i >= 1; i--)
```